# Clear specific ranges on 5 sheets

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have little VBA experience but was given a challenge to build a better audit/order sheet for tobacco products for the company I work for with individual store inputs. They perform these audits each week and I need a button to clear multiple cell ranges on several different sheets. I just want to be able to clear the contents of several ranges with one button but leave all Formulas alone

```
'Clear cells that have count data in them
Worksheets("Master List").Activate
    Range.ClearContents ("B2,B130")
```

This is what I started with as a test and was giving me a debug error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Worksheets("Master List").Range("B2,B130").ClearContents
```

That will clear cells B2 and B130 - if you mean to clear the range from B2 to B130 then you need `Range("B2:B130")`

Note you rarely need to select/activate anything to work with it in VBA - that's an artifact of the macro recorder.